# Changing a button's background color when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

I'm trying to change the `background-color` property of a button using JavaScript. The script checks what the current `background-color` is set to and then toggles it.
This is the JavaScript code:

```
function btnColor(btn,color) {
    var property=document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.background-color == "#f47121") {
        property.style.background-color=Color;
    }
    else {
        property.style.background-color = "#f47121";
    }
}
```

and this is what I pass in html:

```
<input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="Housing" onclick="toggleLayer('transparent1');btnColor('btnHousing','#fff200');" />
```

`toggleLayer` is another function I am using, which works perfectly fine.
I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: background minus color? You've even got spaces around the subtraction operator!

Comment: You are calling the function btnColor, but your function is called setColor

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use jQuery?

Core Javascript is so raw!
If you're just changing the background-color then use the on click event in jQuery:

```
$('#btnHousing').click(function() {
    //Now just reference this button and change CSS
    $(this).css('background-color','#f47121');
});
```

Personally for me it reads so much better then raw javascript.

Regards

Comment: If they're just changing a button background only, there is no need to load in a 32kb file for one event.

Comment: @Seth no one writes just one function in a project..Jquery is an extention and performs much better. yes i agree that loading in the file for one event is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

I made a working example in JsBin : [LINK HERE](http://jsbin.com/ebubop/7/edit)

- I renammed the function to setColor
- I changed the property property.style.background-color by window.getComputedStyle(property).backgroundColor

Comment: It works but it doesn't toggle back to the color you pass it in the html function call i.e. '#fff200'.

Comment: Pass it an rgb value. Hex seems to be converting improperly. Or make your own rgbToHex function that works properly, and pass that as the color.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with rgb values either. I tried putting alerts and for some reason it skips the if statement and jumps to the else part every single time.

Comment: There is a working version : http://jsbin.com/ebubop/7/edit  I updated my original post

Answer (score 2):

Try this function in your javascript :

```
function setColor(btn,color){
    var property=document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "#f47121") {
        property.style.backgroundColor = color;
    } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
    }
}
```

---

To avoid repeating the id of your input in the onclick attribute, you can do this :

HTML :

```
<input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="Housing" onclick="toggleLayer('transparent1');btnColor(this, '#fff200');" />
```

JavaScript (be careful, the var names are case sensitive, cf. Color => color) :

```
function setColor(btn, color){
    if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "#f47121") {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
    } else {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this...

```
function btnColor(btn, color) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "#f47121") {
        property.style.backgroundColor = Color;
    } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
    }
}
```

Hyphenated css attributes are camel cased in JS. 
For example `background-color` becomes -> `backgroundColor`

The above code should work.

Comment: Tried this and with ['backgroundColor'] and ['background-color']. Doesn't work!

Comment: background-color won't work either way. Are you sure you have your function call named properly on the input field? I saw you edited it earlier because the names were conflicting with the function declaration. `document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = color` is how you set the background color, substituting element and color or passing in variables. Double check if `function btnColor` and `onclick="toggleLayer('transparent1');btnColor(this, '#fff200');"` are using the same function names.

Comment: Made sure the function calls were the same and the backgroundColor was used.Still doesn't work.